# Powerpoint in cookiecutter package

Tags: python, powerpoint, cookiecutter

Is it possible to use the cookiecutter variables i.e. `{{ cookiecutter.repo_name }}` inside of a powerpoint document?  Cookie Cutter does not seem to be picking up my variables inside of text boxes it will change the title of the powerpoint, but the content remains as `{{ cookiecutter.repo_name }}`.

My company is very powerpoint driven and has templates for projects that would serve as a readme file.  I would like to be able to fill out the basic project information (Name, Description, Contributors) within the powerpoint using cookie cutter.

Comment: What happened when you tried it out yourself?

Comment: I'm not seeing where cookiecutter has any support for PowerPoint files. I appears to be oriented toward plain-text files, which is what I would expect from that sort of tool. Was there something that gave you the idea this would work? It's possible you could write your own extension or plugin or whatever to do what you're describing, but I don't see any native support for that. Am I missing something?